# Order mismatch between stdout and stderr in bash

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I am executing a bash command in interactive shell as 
`./somescript.sh`

It gives output as

```
OS platform is: linux2
killall agent
agent: no process killed
```

where third line comes from stderr.

But when I execute in the subshell as

```
var=$('./somescript.sh' 2>&1)
agent: no process killed
OS platform is: linux2
killall agent
```

Why did the agent: no process killed is printing in the first line now?
How can I make it consistent to align both of them?

Edit:
However when I did ,
`var=$('./somescript.sh' 1>&2)` 
I can see that it's giving the output in correct order in bash debug mode. But it's not getting stored in the variable var.

Comment: You would need to change ./somescript.sh to redirect from the command that is writing to stderr.

Comment: @StephenC I guess, you are telling to do like 1>&2 right? In that case, how do I print stderr? variable will contain only stdout right? not stderr..

Comment: I can't answer those questions without seeing the script, and understanding what it does,

Comment: *"However when I did , `var=$('./somescript.sh' 1>&2)` as suggested by StephenC"* - That is NOT what I suggested!  What I actually said is that you need to **change** the **script**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why did the agent: no process killed is printing in the first line now?

I guess that is, because stdout is buffered, while stderr is not (or not so much). So stderr get's flushed after the line `agent: no process killed` is streamed while `stdout` is flushed after the script `./somescript.sh` exists. So the first to show up on the screen is the first flushed stream - ie. stderr. While running in console, stderr and stdout both are set to be line buffed, int command substitution I guess bash set's stdout to be fully buffered.

> How can I make it consistent to align both of them?

You can try setting line buffering in command substitution. `var=$(stdbuf -oL -eL ./somescript.sh 2>&1)`